# if statement nested in a for loop

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop

```
c = file('cluster_info.txt')
for i in zip(ys[-10:],result): # has ten elements
    for j in c.readlines():
        cluster = j.split(',')
        if q in cluster:
            m = (q[i],cluster[0])
            f = pylab.figure() # code for plot starts here
            for n, fname in enumerate(m):
                image=Image.open(fname).convert("L")
                arr=np.asarray(image)
                f.add_subplot(2, 1, n)  # this line outputs images on top of each other
                pylab.imshow(arr,cmap=cm.Greys_r)
            pylab.title("%s, Top:Predicted,Bottom:Observed" %i[0])
            pylab.show()
        else:
            continue
```

This is a snippet from a larger code, and I expect to produce 10 images/plots but no plots are produced by python. I think I am not nesting the if and else: correctly in the for loop. Please tell me what is wrong here.

Comment: Where is do-my-work-for-me tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what is your intention of `else: continue`? if you want to continue with the outer loop (`i`), you'd better use `else:break`. otherwise you may just as well delete the `else` branch

also, `i` does not seem to be used in your loop at all? it can't be right

Comment: I need to continue through the loop in j and then continue through loop in i

Comment: should there be two else: at the end?

Comment: this question is very hard to answer (and actually a good candiate to down-vote). if seems that `q in cluster` was never true. try to find out why this is the case (what are the values of `q` and `cluster` in each iteration). also, check the value of `m` to see if the `n, fname` loop is ever executed